# Options for DNS Cache on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, cache

I have an application which frequently queries the same domain name a few times every second, but may then back off for a minute or so afterwards before starting the cycle again. The DNS resolution is starting to become a bottleneck with the standard systemd resolved setup as the cache ttl is too low it seems.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and I've seen I can potential use unbind, bind, dnsmasq but I'm unsure which is good to be using in my situation? Along with steps for the install.

I'm really just after the cache mechanism as I know the endpoint isnt going to be chaning frequently.

Comment: Abandoning domain names all together and doing requests straight to the remote IP is not an option? Same with just overriding DNS and specifying the domain name in /etc/hosts statically?

Comment: Also, I don't think that systemd-resolved could possibly be your bottleneck. Unless you consider bottle neck = one request after several thousands takes a bit longer. The cache should remain valid until it either: gets invalidated by changes to network configuration or domain TTL expires.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107734), unless you already saw it and it didn't work